# Не центрируется карта google maps если есть дополнительные локации

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api

После того как добавил дополнительные локации на карту, она центрируется по этим локациям, а не по указанному центру. Как исправить?

```
<script>

    var locations = [
      ['Title 1', 54.032176, 23.961659000000054, 'Address 1'],
      ['Title 2', 54.677361, 25.130806, 'Address 2'],
      ['Title 3', 54.0231368, 23.973504999999932, 'Address 3']
    ];

    function initMap() {

        var myOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(54.6871555,25.279651400000034),
          zoom: 12,
          mapTypeControl: false,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP

        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),myOptions);

        new AutocompleteDirectionsHandler(map);

        setMarkers(map,locations);
    }

    function setMarkers(map,locations){

        var marker, i

        for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++)
         {  

         var loan = locations[i][0]
         var lat = locations[i][1]
         var long = locations[i][2]
         var add =  locations[i][3]

         latlngset = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);

          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({  
                  map: map, title: loan , position: latlngset  
                });
                map.setCenter(marker.getPosition())


                //var content = "Loan Number: " + loan +  '</h3>' + "Address: " + add 
                var content = loan 

          var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow()

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click', (function(marker,content,infowindow){ 
                return function() {
                   infowindow.setContent(content);
                   infowindow.open(map,marker);
                };
            })(marker,content,infowindow)); 

        }
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Не центрировать карту по локации при создании маркера. Т.е., убрать map.setCenter(marker.getPosition())

Comment: Точно... Спасибо большое.